# Writing Capybara expectations to verify phone numbers

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm using AWS Textract to pull information from PDF documents. After the scanned text is returned from AWS and persisted to a var, I'm doing this:

`phone_number = '(555) 123-4567'`

`scanned_pdf_text.should have_text phone_number`

But this fails about 20% of the time because of the non-deterministic way that AWS is returning the scanned PDF text. On occasion, the phone numbers can appear either of these two ways:

`(555)123-4567` or `(555) 123-4567`

Some of this scanned text is very large, and I'd prefer not to go through the exercise of sanitizing the text coming back if I can avoid it (I'm also not good at regex usage). I also think using `or` logic to handle both cases seems to be a little heavy handed just to check text that is so similar (and clearly near-identical to the human eye).

Is there an `rspec` matcher that'll allow me to check on this text? I'm also using `Capybara.default_normalize_ws = true` but that doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: What is scanned_pdf_text? (string, capybara page, etc) - Is the only difference around spaces? If scanned_pdf_text isn't a string, is it actually a dynamic page or are you guaranteed the element is immediately available with the contents you want to match on?

Comment: `phone_number = '(555) 123-4567'` – you already know the phone number in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `scanned_pdf_text` is a string and the only differences you're seeing is in spaces then you can just get rid of the spaces and compare

```
scanned_pdf_text.gsub(/\s+/, '').should eq('(555)123-4567') # exact

scanned_pdf_text.gsub(/\s+/, '').should match('(555)123-4567') # partial

scanned_pdf_text.gsub(/\s+/, '').should have_text('(555)123-4567') # partial
```